# PHP: Use htmlspecialchars only between defined markers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I've a string with HTML-Tags in a PHP-Variable, i.e.:

```
 $str = '<html>
         <body>
         <div id="box1">[CODE]<span class="test">Hello World</span>[/CODE]</div>
         <div id="box2">[CODE]<strong class="test2">Nice to meet you!</strong>[/CODE]</div>
         </body>
         </html>';
```

Now I wanna parse the string and use *htmlspecialchars* but only inside the markers [CODE] and [/CODE]. All tags outside the markers should be ignored.

The result should be:

```
$str = ' [...] <div id="box1">&lt;span class="test"&gt;Hello World&lt;/span&gt;</div> [...]';
```

Is there a solution via *preg_replace*?

Comment: You might want to consider [PHP BBcode](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) instead

Comment: You also want to remove **CODE**  from the string ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$str = '<html>
         <body>
         <div id="box1">[CODE]<span class="test">Hello 
         [CODE] World</span>[/CODE]</div>
         <div id="box2">[CODE]<strong class="test2">Nice to meet you!</strong>[/CODE]</div>
         </body>
         </html>';

echo preg_replace_callback ('/\[CODE\](.*?)\[\/CODE\]/s',  function ($matches) {return htmlspecialchars($matches[1]);}, $str);
```

result

```
<html>
         <head/><body>
         <div id="box1">&lt;span class=&quot;test&quot;&gt;Hello 
         [CODE] World&lt;/span&gt;</div>
         <div id="box2">&lt;strong class=&quot;test2&quot;&gt;Nice to meet you!&lt;/strong&gt;</div>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: @PedroLobito That's the point. This is BB Code so you want the BB Code tags removed

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question then.

Comment: You pattern fails when there is more than one `[code]` tag in the same line and when there are line-breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for, also eliminating the `[CODE]` markers:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/\[CODE\](.*)\[\/CODE\]/';
$replace = function($m) { return htmlspecialchars($m[1]); };
$subject = <<<EOT
<html>
<body>
<div id="box1">[CODE]<span class="test">Hello World</span>[/CODE]</div>
<div id="box2">[CODE]<strong class="test2">Nice to meet you!</strong>[/CODE]</div>
</body>
</html>
EOT;

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replace, $subject);
```

The output of the above is:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="box1">&lt;span class=&quot;test&quot;&gt;Hello World&lt;/span&gt;</div>
<div id="box2">&lt;strong class=&quot;test2&quot;&gt;Nice to meet you!&lt;/strong&gt;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting: an anonymous down vote on a perfectly working answer. LOL

Comment: Hi arkascha, i'm testing your code but unfortunately the output contains only the parts between the [CODE] and [/CODE] Tags. Everything outside the [CODE]-Tag is missing. What I make wrong?

Comment: @Christoph I am sorry, I cannot agree with your statement. The output clearly contains the portions outside the `[CODE]` markers too. Exactly how it is shown as output in the answer above. It might however be that you try to look at the result using an html browser. In that case the browser will obviously interpret the outer html markup, so that it is not visible in a literal sense. Try using `var_dump()` instead of the `echo` statement, or enclosing the output in `<pre>` tags or try the code on CLI.

Comment: / yes, i fixed the problem by using <pre>-Tags. But now I've the problem that the function only fires onces. In fact: The first element between [CODE] and [/CODE] is parsed correctly, the second element is be ignored ;-(

Comment: @Christoph Again: I cannot agree with that. The output as I posted it above is _exactly_ what I get if I execute the code. So _both_ contained `[CODE]` sections are correctly replaced, I just check again, to be sure. There is no reason why the replacement should be limited. There must be some other difference in how you use that code above.